# getJSON callback did not work

Tags: javascript, callback, getjson

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>        
        <script>

        function getprice(){
            $.getJSON("https://api.bithumb.com/public/ticker?Callback=?", function(data) {
                var price = parseFloat(data['data']['closing_price'])
                $('#price').html( price);                  

                });              
          }
```

https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker

poloniex's url is worked well. but bithumb isn't.

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? What errors did you get? Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you don't need `?Callback=?` by the way

Comment: that API sends `access-control-allow-orgin` ... which is not `access-control-allow-origin` - that API also does NOT support JSONP - clearly the owners of `bithumb.com` need a refresher course in **testing**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like said above it has typo in header, you should contact the owner. In meanwhile you can do proxy request using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

```js
function getprice() {
  $.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20FROM%20json%0AWHERE%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.bithumb.com%2Fpublic%2Fticker%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=", function(data) {
    //console.log(data)
    var price = parseFloat(data.query.results.json.data.closing_price)
    $('#price').html(price);
  });
}
getprice();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

price: <span id="price">...</span>
```